# How can I resolve a problem with Parcel? Console error (html links as js files)

Tags: javascript, parcel

I have an error with a web (https://github.com/imanol-argueso/covid19-euskadin) I can´t resolve. I´m using javascript with node, and Google Charts API. The browser console returns an error: *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'* (Firefox)

It seems that the browser tries to format the html links of the web as js files. I think the error is related with parcel but I can´t find the solution. Can somebody help me?

The error occurs in almost all the html files of the web, including the index.html (https://github.com/imanol-argueso/covid19-euskadin/tree/master/src/covid19). Chrome console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' xxxxx.js (the xxxx is the name of another html file of the web).

Comment: Hey urki, Can you provide a bit more about what you have and where exactly the issue is occuring. The link to GitHub is not really pointing to a specific file, so its a bit difficult to help. But welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi Gert, the error occurs in almost all the html files of the web, including the index.html (https://github.com/imanol-argueso/covid19-euskadin/tree/master/src/covid19). Chrome console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  xxxxx.js (the xxxx is the name of another html file of the web). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the problem. Google Charts html code proposal is like that:

```
<div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Moving the style from the html to the css solved the problem, I don´t understand what is the reason of the error but the error disappeared from all the files.